# Jquery animation both on document ready and on link load

Tags: jquery

Currently, I have an animation that works on hover and slides panels to the left and right to reveal the content beneath it.  What I'm looking to do is to have the panels slide left and right on the initial loading of the home page and then when people click a link to a separate page, the panels return to meet in the center of the page and once the data is loaded, they move back to the right and left to once again reveal the data below it.

I'm not sure where to take what I have to make all that work.  Here's what I've got thus far in generic for the css:

```
    body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;width:100%;}
.overlay_container {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
    .box_container{  
position:relative; /* important */  
width:1280px; /* we must set a specific width of the container, so it doesn't strech when the image starts moving */  
height:953px; /* important */  
overflow:hidden; /* hide the content that goes out of the div */  
/*just styling bellow*/  
background: black;  
color:white;  
}  
.images_holder{  
position:absolute; /* this is important, so the div is positioned on top of the text */  
}  
.image_div {  
    position:relative; /* important so we can work with the left or right indent */  
    overflow:hidden; /* hide the content outside the div (this is how we will hide the part of the image) */  
    width:50%; /* make it 50% of the whole images_holder */  
    float:left; /* make then inline */  
}  
.right img{  
    margin-left: -100%; /* 100% is in this case 50% of the image, so this is how we show the second part of the image */  
}  
.clear{  
    clear:both;  
}
```

and then the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //when the user hovers over the div that contains our html...
    $('.box_container').hover(function(){
        //... we get the width of the div and split it by 2  ...
        var width = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;
        /*... and using that width we move the left "part" of the image to left and right "part"
        to right by changing it's indent from left side or right side... */
        $(this).find('.left').animate({ right : width },{queue:false,duration:500});
        $(this).find('.right').animate({ left : width },{queue:false,duration:500});
    }, function(){
        //... and when he hovers out we get the images back to their's starting position using the same function... '
        $(this).find('.left').animate({ right : 0 },{queue:false,duration:500});
        $(this).find('.right').animate({ left : 0 },{queue:false,duration:500});
        //... close it and that's it
    });
```

});

and the html:

```
    <div class='box_container'>  

        <!--START THE IMAGE PARTS HOLDER-->  
        <div class='images_holder'>  

            <!--INSERT THE SAME IMAGE IN 2 DIVS, THEY BOTH HAVE image_div CLASS AND left OR right CLASS DEPENDING ON POSITION-->  
            <div class='image_div left'><img class='box_image' src='1280overlay.jpg' style='width:1280px'/></div>  
            <div class='image_div right'><img class='box_image' src='1280overlay.jpg' style='width:1280px'/></div>  

            <!-- WE USED CSS FLOAT PROPERY, SO WE NEED TO CLEAR NOW-->  
            <div class='clear'></div>  

        </div>  
        <!--END THE IMAGE PARTS HOLDER-->  

        <!--START THE TEXT-->  
        Just some dummy text.  
        <!--END THE TEXT-->  

</div>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle of this?

Comment: I would do it this way.....make all your anchor links return false on click to prevent the page loading...and in the .animate() method put a callback function that sets window.location.href to the href attribute of the link they clicked

Comment: fiddled - http://jsfiddle.net/z4yMV/